# What would different groups of dinosaurs be called if they still lived with humans?

Tags: biology, dinosaurs

In my world, dinosaurs live along with humans, so I'm wondering what groups of dinosaurs would be called. I was wanting something unique, but still specific. A pack of velociraptors doesn't sound the same as a swarm of velociraptors. Is there an officials name for groups of dinosaurs that I'm just oblivious too? I'm not wanting to just call everything a pack, flock, herd, or school, but a more specific name like a parade of elephants. I believe it will make the world more interesting.

Edit, I had thought that animal grouping names like herds and packs had a scientific name, but apparently it is completely opinion based. Understood now.

Comment: Sauropoda.. same as now.. any reason to suppose they wouldn't be called what they're called now .. Ah! hang on, a group of them, why would we use any different nomenclature than we use for other animals? if they still lived they'd just be normal animals like any other, so why would anyone develop special words for them above and beyond those we already have for group of animals, they wouldn't be special if they were still here.

Comment: Do birds still exist? as they're the closest relatives to dinosaurs I suppose there might be a movement among some to use the same words we do for a group of birds, but pack, herd and flock depending on if they're carnivores herbivores, animal size and domestication status etc would seem more likely for common use to me than any special words.

Comment: He's looking for the collection name, like this: https://arapahoelibraries.org/blogs/post/names-for-groups-of-animals/ Unfortunately, such things were standardized before we knew that dinosaurs existed, so there is no established collective word for dinosaurs. Even more unfortunately, that makes all answers to this question a matter of opinion.

Comment: Names are surprisingly arbitrary. Humans could create whatever collective nouns they want, provided their language supports collective nouns. This makes this question far too subjective and opinion based to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: (1) There are no "official" names for anything, at least not in English. Unlike the French language, the English language does not have any kind of official body empowered to standardize the language. (2) *Very many* of collective name for $x$ found in various works are not actually in use and never were; I would be astonished to meet with an unkindness of ravens or a murmuration of starlings except in a humorous context. (3) A parade of elephants is a set of elephants parading for show; it does not mean several elephants going about their business together, that is, a herd of elephants.

Comment: In a mostly paleontologist player dnd game we used a trample of sauropods, a herd of triceratops, a ballet of stegosaurs, a pack of utahraptors, and a massacre of t-rexs. although there was an argument for a F**k of T-rexs just because that was the sound you make when you see 8 t-rexs at the same time hunting together and you realize you are made of meat.

Comment: @AlexP Nowadays the "[Académie Française](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Fran%C3%A7aise)" barely have any actual power beyond conservative political parties (and even then...). Noone buys the official dictionary since it is from the previous century. On their website, the unfinished 9th edition proudly promotes they caught up with what happened the 11th september 2001, which tells a lot . Moreover, its gerontocratic organisation prevents most official introductions of new words, like in the I.T. domain for instance.

Comment: To summarize the vote closure: we do not answer questions about names or how things are named. Names are nothing more than an aesthetic and have nothing to do with worldbuilding or world rules. They can be created for any reason, are wholly opinion-based, and asking for names violates a number of rules in the [help]. Please remember, if you're tempted to ask, "I need some ideas?" there's a 99.9% chance that you're asking the wrong question or you're asking the question in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a reason that all dinosaurs would all share the same naming convention.  Flock, herd, pride, school, and pack all seem like they could be used to refer to different types of dinosaurs; flocks for flyers, herd for large masses of herbivores, pride or pack for groups of carnivores and school for swimmers.

A murder of velociraptors sounds lovely.  Likewise a stampede of sauropods (whether they are actually stampeding or not), a crash of ankylosaurs (or, better, a *crush*), and an apocalypse of titanosaurs all sound evocative.

Answer (score 0):

Collective nouns for extant reptilians:

- A group of lizards is called a 'lounge'
- A group of iguanas (iguana?) is called a 'mess'
- A group of alligators is called a 'congregation'
- A group of crocodiles is called a 'float'

likely any group names for fictional existing dinosaurs would be as varied as species of dinosaur.

helpful link: [List of animal names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names)

Comment: You do realize that these silly names are not really in use, except as markers of levity? And that actually using them will mark the text work as having (slightly) humorous intent? Please give a citation to a serious or at least not-intended-to-be-funny work using the phrases "a lounge of lizards" or "a float of crocodiles". No, wanna-be lists of names for groups of animals do not count. Only actual use of the phrases in the wild, so to say.

Comment: @AlexP --- Actually these kinds of words *are* in use in English. Some are very common and can be found in the lowest registers of the language; others, like these might only be found in higher registers.

Comment: @elemtilas: So it should not be hard to give a citation to a book or two showing that the phrase "a float of crocodiles" has real-world use. You know, *"... and then at the shouted warning of the guide, the travellers turned their gaze from watching the mess of iguanas on the bank to look at the float of crocodiles spying on them from the brown waters of the river"*, or something similar.

Comment: @AlexP Personally I agree with you, but I was surprised to find [examples of some of these and others](https://www.dictionary.com/e/strange-animal-groups-listicle/) but as I do some really rapid research it appears these names are appearing in the language, not because of any scientific or even demographic consensus for their use, but through literary artistry. The credibility level would (it appears) be equal with me writing a poem about the oddities of humanity and calling it "A Humor of Humans" and then making the claim, "yeah, that's what you call a group of humans."

Comment: @all I agree with the above. I should have been more clear on how abitrary the names truly are.

Comment: In other words, while we've found a teaspoon of credibility for this answer, the reality is that we can't find an official etymology of these terms - but that really doesn't matter anyway because it's the policy of this Stack to not answer questions about names or naming conventions - they're being almost always entirely arbitrary and opinion-based.

Comment: @AlexP --- You are 100% correct. It is not at all hard give a citation or two. You're a smart lad and I bet you can google some up all on your own.

Comment: @elemtilas: I did, before adding a comment based on my fallible memory. I didn't find any. Could you enlighten me? `"lounge of lizards" site:gutenberg.org` $\rightarrow$ No results found for "lounge of lizards" site:gutenberg.org. `"group of lizards" site:gutenberg.org` $\rightarrow$ 19 results. `"float of crocodiles" site:gutenberg.org` $\rightarrow$ No results found for "float of crocodiles" site:gutenberg.org. `"group of crocodiles" site:gutenberg.org` $\rightarrow$ 4 results.

Comment: @AlexP --- There are literally scores of these words. Check out clouds of gnats, skulk of foxes, a band of gorillas, and many more! Also check out [this query](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/why-are-there-so-many-specific-words-for-groups-of-animals). A lot of these words are novel, no doubt, but the tradition behind animal group names is ancient in English. Words like pack, herd, flock, sounder, murder, plague and litter are extremely commonplace. Others like clowder and parliament and lounge (that one deffo sounds new!) are rarer.

Comment: The question regardless of suitabmerit to the stack. Without a doubt has merit. I don't understand the reaction. No one would use a phrase such as, the herd of lions stalked the pride of zebra..